# Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to getPrice() must be an instance of Rectangle, none given

Tags: php, oop, polymorphism

I am just trying to calculate the price of the area of a rectangl outside the rectangle class which returns it's area. Just trying an example of polymorphism. Am I doing something wrong? 
I am new to OOP aproach. Here's my code:

```
// getting the area
class Rectangle{

    public $height;
    public $width;

    public function __construct($height, $width){

        $this->height = $height;
        $this->width = $width;
    }

    public function getArea(){

        return $this->height * $this->width. "<br />";
    }

}
```

Outside the class I created the function `getPrice()

```
`function getPrice(Rectangle $rectangle){

    return $rectangle->getArea() * 0.25;

}
```

Creating the instance and printing out.

```
$rectangle = new Rectangle(12, 15);
echo getPrice();
```

The error showing is :

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to getPrice() must be an instance of Rectangle, none given, called in /var/www/html/crashcourse/oop_php/phpacademy/polymorphism.php on line 41 and defined in /var/www/html/crashcourse/oop_php/phpacademy/polymorphism.php on line 31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look to getPrice () function has a $ rectangle parameter of type Rectangle class, you need to pass the Rectangle object that is instantiated class.
Do as follows:

```
$ rectangle = new Rectangle (12, 15);
echo getPrice ($ rectangle);
```

Comment: Shoot. Didn't realize. Thanks a lot mate.! but there ain't gonna be any spaces between the `$` and `rectangle`. I don't know if that's a typo of yours or you used deliberately.